# How to sum a bash array of numbers (some in scientific notation)?

Tags: bash, awk, array, bc, math

Since the following command using bc does not work for numbers in scientific notation, I was wondering about an alternative, e.g. using awk?

```
sum=$( IFS="+"; bc <<< "${arrValues[*]}" )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sum=$(
  awk 'BEGIN {t=0; for (i in ARGV) t+=ARGV[i]; print t}' "${arrValues[@]}"
)
```

With zsh (in case you don't *have* to use `bash`), since it supports floating point numbers internally:

```
sum=$((${(j[+])arrValues}))
```

With `ksh93`:

If you need the kind of precision that `bc` provides, you could pre-process the numbers so that `12e23` is changed to `(12*10^23)`:

```
sum=$(
  IFS=+
  sed 's/\([0-9.]*\)[eE]\([-+]*[0-9]*\)/(\1*10^\2)/g' <<< "${arrValues[*]}" |
    bc -l
)
```

Comment: @MaVe, the `+` character is not special to the shell and doesn't need quoted (quoting won't harm though).

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -l -e 'print sum(@ARGV)' -- "${array[@]}"
```

Or for arbitrary precision:

```
perl -Mbignum -MList::Util=sum -l -e 'print sum(0, @ARGV)' -- "${array[@]}"
```

(with a literal `0` added to force the sum to be made with bignums).