# Add two doubles on bash

Tags: bash, awk, numeric-data, bc

I'm trying to add two doubles

```
y1=0.17580197E-01
y2=0.11979236E-02
sum=`echo $y1+$y2 | bc -l`
```

the above script gives me sum = -2.704405652. How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Related: [How to sum a bash array of numbers (some in scientific notation)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99092/how-to-sum-a-bash-array-of-numbers-some-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know its different for scientific notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with awk with this command:

```
sum=`echo|awk -v y1=$y1 -v y2=$y2 '{print y1+y2}'`
```

As suggested in comment awk can be rewritten on this way (to avoid echo)

```
sum=`awk -v y1=$y1 -v y2=$y2 'BEGIN {print y1+y2}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "$y1 $y2" | awk  '{print $1+$2}'
0.0187781
```

Just print the two values separated by space and add the first two fields with awk

Answer (score 0):

To add with bc the numbers should not have the scientific exponent. In other words, the numbers should be in float (`%f`) format. That could be done with:

```
y1=0.17580197E-01
y2=0.11979236E-02
sum=$(printf '%.20f+%.20f\n' "$y1" "$y2" | bc -l)
```